# Understanding MDP variants and "model-free" RL algorithms

Tags: reinforcement-learning, markov-hidden-model

RL is based on MDPs. But MDPs have other useful variants such as Semi MDP (variable time), POMDP (partially observable states) etc.

Some industrial problems seem to be better suited for SMDP and/or POMDPs. For example optimizing maintenance, the time between maintenance events is variable. And, some states of equipment may not available for measurement directly -- hence we have "partially observable" states.

If I decide to use a model-free algorithm such as DDPG or PPO, the theory of which I think is based on **MDP** -- am I **comprising** on the state or model definition? Will it create a less efficient agent?

Of course I may not have a choice as creating an accurate environment is out of question. But just trying to understand.

Appreciate your thoughts.

Comment: Technically yes - but very rarely in the real world do we encounter true MDPs, crack on with model-free.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The performance of a classical agent strongly depends on how close the observation approximates the true state of the environment. The state is sometimes defined as all we need to know to model the dynamics forward in time. Therefore, the closer it is possible to infer the dynamics of the environment with the information provided, the better the performance.

A common case study in RL is Atari. There, one observation (pixel image) alone would be insufficient to make progress at all. But if you stack consecutive images together, then this can provide sufficient information for an agent developed for MDPs like DQN to learn games like Breakout, Space Invaders or Pong.
Now, this is not enough for games that require memory, like Montezuma's Revenge, which would be considered as a POMDP.

To address partial observability, a general idea is to use a recurrent neural network (often LSTM or GRU) instead of a feed-forward network in the actor and critic to give the agent additional context if required to make good decisions. The use of an LSTM, plus additional implementation tricks, can give strong results in all Atari games (see [R2D2](https://openreview.net/pdf?id=r1lyTjAqYX)). Also, essentially PPO with a (huge) LSTM was also able to reach super-human performance in DOTA2, see [OpenAI Five](https://openai.com/five/).

To take an example in robotics deployed to the real world. Assume we know the positions and velocities of all the joints. Then this information is still partial in practice, as we ignore other factors (like friction, wind speed, terrain). However, it would perform still be able to perform decently. If we had only the positions, then we may be able to infer the velocities by using an LSTM and make it work. If we had only access to the information of one joint, it would probably never work.

Comment: Thank you Matorbi. This idea of LSTM to address a pomdp is enlightening for me. Your explanation help me understand the nuances better now.